# How do I create a successful weather api get request in Ionic thats using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, openweathermap

The good part:
I can create a successful api call here:
[Successful call to Api](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=fe9cbae0062a1e59f31b3f005cf6476f)

However, I am not sure if I'm just not declaring the string correctly or the data I'm passing in to the getWeather request method.

```
/* My Service File: Weather Service */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
/* Properties */
  url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  apiKey: 'fe9cbae0062a1e59f31b3f005cf6476f';

  constructor(public http: HTTP) {
    console.log('Weather Service Working?');
    this.url ='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather&appid='+this.apiKey;
  }
  getWeather(city, state){
    return this.http.get(this.url+'/'+state+'/'city);
  }

}
```

**Screenshot of the error**:
[image]

Then, I also wanted to try to use the Service, and there are no errors here, but there are errors in the console now

**Console Error**
[image]

and the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from '../services/weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
weather: any;
location: {
  city: string;
  state: string;
};
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.location = {
      city: 'Miami',
      state: 'FL'
    };
    this.weatherService.getWeather(this.location.city, this.location.state).subscribe(weather =>
      console.log(weather));
  }
}
```

Updated Error:
[image]

Now it says my key is incorrect, however the key works fine here:
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=fe9cbae0062a1e59f31b3f005cf6476f

Answer (score 2):

The types your are using I think are not correct also the http I think you should stick to the Angular HttpClient at least that's how I do it when working with angular and Ionic. Try this way:

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    export class WeatherService {
    /* Properties */
      url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
      apiKey: 'fe9cbae0062a1e59f31b3f005cf6476f';

     // I've changed the constructor
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Weather Service Working?');
        this.url ='api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather&appid='+this.apiKey;
      }

     // This function will return an Observable If you want a promise you will 
     // have to convert it
      getWeather(city, state): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/${state}/${city}`);
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: It works with the above code and solves it.  Thank you :)
But, yes I can do it in Angular but I'm trying to learn the Ionic framework

Comment: I really want to try with ionics native HTTP way:
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

Comment: and now I'm also getting console log errors :(

Comment: For the error message it seems like you are trying to do the request against your own machine instead the API url

Comment: Thank you! I updated my code but now its saying my API key is not correct but when I try the url with the api key by it self, it works over here: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=fe9cbae0062a1e59f31b3f005cf6476f  .  So I'm not sure what the error is about.

Comment: On the error screenshot the value of the api key is undefined. Take a look on that.